# Work on binary relations using their matrices

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I have three questions I am practicing, I have the answers but I want to understand these matrices concepts.

1. Let r by a relation with identity matrix \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. Which one of the following is the identity matrix of r^{2}?
   Select one:
   a. \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
   b. \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
   c. \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
   d. \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
   e. \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

I know that the answer is the following  but I am unsure how to arrive there. Thanks for any  help

\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\ \:1&1&1\\ \:0&0&1\end{pmatrix}

2.Which of the following matrices is the matrix of a symmetric and reflexive relation?
Select one:
a. \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
b. \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
c. \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
d. \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
e. \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

I know that reflexive has the same in the diagonal but I am not sure how to identify the symmetric. I know that the answer is 
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}

3.If A = { 1,2,3,4} and q ={ (a,b)| 3|a - b} is a relation on A then which one of the following is the identity matrix on q^{2}?
Select one:
a. \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
b. \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
c. \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
d. \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
e. \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}

I know the answer is : \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}

but again I really want to understand the concepts behind the matrices. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Language clarification - we refer to an/the identity matrix as the matrix with ones on the diagonal, zeroes everywhere else.

Comment: Could please explain the concepts and how to arrive at those answers, I have been trying for the past couple of hours but no avail

Comment: 1. Just multiply the matrix $R$ with itself!

Comment: Have you at least understood what @Sean Robertson has said: $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is **not** identity matrix. $3 \times 3$ Identity matrix is **always** $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: How can the identity matrix be always the same  for every matrix? Thanks for any clarification

Comment: I have modified your title in order that more people can be attracted to your question, being understood that the name "identity matrix" has nothing to do  here.

Comment: See for example (https://www.cs.clemson.edu/course/cpsc827/material/Language%20Theory/Binary%20Relations.pdf) nowhere you will find "identity matrix": you will see "boolean matrix associated with (or defining) the relation.

Comment: Thank for changing the title @JeanMarie